# Connect two docker containers

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have two containers, the first one with a `django` and the second one with `postgresql`.

Well, in my first server I have running `django` and I'm trying to connect it with the second one.
The second container has the port `32770` exposed but internally running in the port `5432`.
In my local machine, I have the connection:
Server: 'Localhost'
Port: 32770
User: 'myuser'
Password: ''

And it's connecting, but with my `django` container, I'm getting this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 32770?
```

The same happens for the port `5432`

How I can connect both servers?

Comment: Are you running the containers using docker-compose or individually? post your docker-compose file or the docker run commands you have used

Comment: I'm running them individually @TarunLalwani

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your are running the containers individually you have different options

**Run django on network of postgres container**

```
$ docker run -d ... postgres
<container id>

$ docker run -d ... --net container:<containerid> django
```

Then django can find postgres on `localhost:5432`

**Run django and postgres as named containers container**

```
$ docker run --name postgresdb -d ... postgres
<container id>

$ docker run -d ...  django
```

Now django can find db on `postgresdb:5432`

**Run both containers on host**

```
$ docker run --net host -d ... postgres
<container id>

$ docker run -d ... --net host django
```

Then django can find postgres on `localhost:5432`

**Run containers on same network**

```
$ docker network create mynet

$ docker run --name postgresdb --net mynet -d ... postgres
<container id>

$ docker run --net mynet -d ...  django
```

Now django can find db on `postgresdb:5432`

**Connect to the host IP and mapped port**

```
$ docker run -d -p 32770:5432 .... postgres

$ docker run -d .... django
```

Django can now connect to the DB on `<yourdockerhostip>:32770`.

Better option is to run it using `docker-compose`. Learn more on https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Great answer with many options to accomplish this. I ran a new network and hooked up both containers to it. Heads up, I'm not sure the second option works without having the containers on the same network

Answer (score 2):

Would be better if you had sent your config file. But, i think that you need use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). In the documentation you can find about the communication between the containers.

Simple config exemple:

```
system_mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6.27
  container_name: system_mysql
  hostname: system_mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_USER=user
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=databse
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
django:
  restart: always
  container_name: django
  hostname: django
  .
  . continue with [environment, volumes, build]
  .
  depends_on:
    - system_mysql
```