# I can't connect one spring container and another with mysql using docker run

Tags: docker

I am trying to connect my springboot application with my mysql database but without success. I have tried putting them on the same network, but the springboot container closes with the following error.

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

docker commands

```
docker build -t frarm2014/spring-boot3-rest:v1 .

docker network create spring-network
    
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-springboot3 --network spring-network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ThePassword -e MYSQL_USER=springuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=ThePassword -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db_example mysql:5.7
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name rest-springboot3 --network spring-network frarm2014/spring-boot3-rest:v1
```

application properties

```
loggin.level.org.springframework=debug
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-springboot3:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

When I run the application from the jar or from vscode, I can make calls to the mysql container created with the docker run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect two docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327006/connect-two-docker-containers)

Comment: I used the fourth option, it is the same and I did not get results

Comment: You're using `localhost` instead of the name of the other container.

Comment: Delete everything, follow the steps again, and same error. I got the same error when trying the same thing with docker compose. I think something is wrong in the pom, I edit the question with the complete pom and the changes in the commands.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database from your Spring app?

Comment: It is my understanding that this property does that job : spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-springboot3:3306/db_example